# Emails from Devise (Rails) not being delivered (log says 'email sent to <address>'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise, smtp, gmail

I've setup smtp exactly like described in this tutorial:

http://rubyonrailshelp.wordpress.com/2014/01/02/setting-up-mailer-using-devise-for-forgot-password

I'm sending a "Forgot my password email" to users. When I supply the address, everything seems to work fine, and when I check the logs, it says: "Email sent to ". However no email is delivered on my end :(I've tried two different email addresses.

Any thoughts? I've followed about 5 different tutorials for setting up SMPT for devise but none of them have worked for me. This one seemed to be pretty sure of itself :)

EDIT: I also set up MailCatcher locally, and when using one of the settings I've tried, it actually caught an email, but again, no email was delivered to me.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I stopped using the Devise:Mailer class and wrote my own UserMailer class and copied the default views to its views folder.